# Parsing XML with jQuery... problem retrieving elements

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

An XML snippet:

```
<results>
   <review>
      <api_detail_url>http://api.giantbomb.com/review/1/</api_detail_url>
      <game>
         <api_detail_url>http://api.giantbomb.com/game/20462/</api_detail_url>
         <id>20462</id>
         <name>SingStar</name>
      </game>
      <score>4</score>
   </review>
</results>
```

And here's my testing code, just to show whether data is being collected or not ('data' holds the XML):

```
var element;

$(data).find('review').each(function() {
    element = $(this).find('name').text();
});

alert(element);
```

Now here's the problem, only this query actually returns data:

```
$(this).find('score').text();
```

The alert box in this case would pop up with '4'.  These two other queries don't return anything (the alert box is blank):

```
$(this).find('api_detail_url').text();
$(this).find('name').text();
```

I've tried using jQuery selectors, like...

```
$(this).find('game > name').text();
```

...but that doesn't work, either, still get a blank alert box.  Am I missing something?  Testing is being done in Chrome.

Comment: This works just fine for me in Chrome and Firefox. Post more code, because your problem isn't with this stuff. Here's what I did with your example content: http://gutfullofbeer.net/xml.html

Comment: Yup, you were right.  I was using a PHP script to fetch the XML, so I decided to dump the XML to the console to take a look.  Seems DOMDocument->saveXML() decided to wrap most everything in <![CDATA[]]> tags :/

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this plugin can help you http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xmlObjectifier
Try converting the XML to JSON and using the JSON structure henceforth

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

assuming that in xml you have the xml document

```
$(xml).each(function (index, item) {
    $reviews = $(item).find('review');

    //assuming that you have more than one review in results
    $reviews.each(function (i, rev) {
        var api = $(rev).find('api_detail_url').text();
        var $game = $(rev).find('game');
        var gameApi = $game.find('api_detail_url').text();
        var gameID = $game.find('id').text();
        var gameName = $game.find('name').text();                     

    });

});
```